# Confusion regarding context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding contexts in JavaScript which I find confusing (probably since I'm new to JavaScript/Web dev overall). I am invoking the function initialize and specifying this as the context to run it in, within it I'm subscribing to keyup event from the input element and binds it to this context. However the function search is invoked in window function even though it is invoked by a function that is invoked within the Filter-context. Why is it like that? I thought that a function would be invoked in the invokers context.

```
function Filter() {

    /**
     * Other objects are set to this context (Filter)
     */ 

    var search = function() {
        /// Context here is window
    }

    var initialize = function() {
        /// Context here is this (Filter)
        this.searchBox = $("#search-box");
        this.searchBox.keyup((function() {
            /// Context here is this (Filter) due to the bind()
            var newSearch = this.searchBox.val();
            var previousSearch = this.filterValues.search;

            if (newSearch !== previousSearch) {
                if (newSearch.length === 0)
                    this.filterValues.Search = null;
                else
                    this.filterValues.Search = newSearch;

                clearTimeout(this.searchTimer);
                this.searchTimer = setTimeout(search, 250);
            }
        }).bind(this));
    }

    initialize.call(this);
}
```

Usage:

```
this.filter = new Filter();
```

Comment: Wait, I think I know why! it is the timer thingy which resides within window that invokes search. That has got to be it!

Comment: Yep, that's it. Your code snippet seemed to imply that `search` was meant to be in the context of `window`.

Comment: Definitely. Handling the context within JavaScript is a tongue-twister.

Comment: You seem to have a good handle of it. Generally, if you're *passing* a function as an argument (and care about the context in which it's executed), you have to be explicit about its context.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I just started with JavaScript and have been struggling all day with these kind of things but hopefully I got the hang of it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer:

```
this.searchTimer = setTimeout(search, 250);
```

is replaced with

```
this.searchTimer = setTimeout(search.bind(this), 250);
```

since setTimeout's context is window, and thus search got invoked in window.